# Dispose event for knockoutjs custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I am trying to develop a widget using knockoutjs custom binding.

The widget would subscribe to an observable for the logged in user, so that its UI would change when a user logs in/out. I figured out that the subscribing has to be done in the `init` function, but am unable to figure out where to dispose the subscription once the widget is destroyed, i.e. removed from the DOM.

The documentation mentions `init` and `update` - but how do I "dispose" a custom binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `init` function do something like

```
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
    //act on element disposal
});
```